# Extjs file upload and return message using JSONObject

Tags: java, extjs

I tried uploading an excel file and it worked well but the return message doesn't show. For the return message I use the below code as shown [here](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/12/extjs-4-file-upload-using-apache.html):

```
JSONObject myObj = new JSONObject();
//sets success to true
myObj.put("success", true);
//convert the JSON object to string and send the response back
out.println(myObj.toString());
out.close();
```

For using this class I used the `json-lib.jar`. Further it asks for dependent jars like `ezmorph-1.0.jar` which I am doubtful of using.
Has anyone used the above method to return a message to the front end?
If so, what were the jars used in the process? Please help

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the above by using `json-simple-1.1.jar` instead of `json-lib.jar`.
This created a `JSONObject` without the need of any other jar.